# Build Failed in React Native and Getting java stackoverflowError as well

Tags: javascript, build.gradle

I am unable to solve this problem:

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Farhan Malik\Desktop\rnProjects\TechChloride\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Farhan Malik\Desktop\rnProjects\TechChloride\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Farhan Malik\Desktop\rnProjects\TechChloride\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Farhan Malik\Desktop\rnProjects\TechChloride\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I was trying to Run React NAtive newly created app on Emulator.